# How, or in which pattern, are environment variables listed in a shell (bash)?

Tags: bash, shell, environment

I have a task to implement my own shell in C from scratch for my school.

As a reference, I must take `bash`.

My question is, how are the environ variables listed when either `env` or `printenv` are called?

I've noticed it's neither by creation date nor by alphabetical order.

My shell has its own environment as a `char **`, and I'm wondering how should I shuffle it after a new variable declared so that it imitates `bash` correctly.

I tried running `export a=aaaa` in `bash` and it appeared in the middle of the list.

Comment: Probably implementation-dependent; the kernel may or may not arrange or manipulate the environment as it sees fit, and there is no particular reason to think it's going to be predictable, portable, or pertinent to any application what it does or how it does it.

Comment: @Mampac : Why is the order important? The most natural implementation would be using an associative array, and in most languages, you have no control over the order of the keys anyway. Another idea is to output it sorted, which means that the concrete order depends on the current locale.

Comment: @user1934428 i just wanted to imitate bash as closely as possible, but after discovering there's no certain pattern, i'll just append the new variables at the end of the list

Comment: I guess you will (hopefully) use an associate array for this too. So just use the order you get from your data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how are the environ variables listed when either env or printenv are called?

Both these programs are open source. From [coreutlis/env.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/env.c#L870):

```
  char *const *e = environ;
  while (*e)
    printf ("%s%c", *e++, opt_nul_terminate_output ? '\0' : '\n');
```

From [coreutils/printenv](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/printenv.c):

```
  for (env = environ; *env != NULL; ++env)
    printf ("%s%c", *env, opt_nul_terminate_output ? '\0' : '\n');
```

> I've noticed it's neither by creation date nor by alphabetical order.

Inspecting [glibc/setenv.c](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/setenv.c.html#168) I think it appends the values on the end, and keeps a separate binary search tree (`#include <search.h>`) with variable names for fast searching.

Posix states from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html :

> There is no meaning associated with the order of strings in the environment.

and I think this is enough to give implementations freedom to use any order they want.

> in bash and it appeared in the middle of the list.

There is no reason for Bash to use environ. Bash has its own [export_env](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/variables.c#L164) 2d array, and it keeps variables using its own `HASH_TABLE` implementation - [hashlib.c](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/hashlib.c) and also `VAR_CONTEXT`.